# How can I use HTML attributes in Blazor?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

I am using an input list because I need to contain more than 1,000 data and consider mobile users.
So I am using it as another attribute to hide the real value.

ex)

```
<datalist id="list1">
<option realvalue="1">Option1</option>
</datalist>
<input type="text" list="list1" />
@code{
  private string list1value;
  private void inputchanged()
  {
    listvalue = ???//datalist realvalue
    //etc
  }
}
```

I need to use the real value in code

I want to communicate with DB using real value, but I don't know how to use it even after searching

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you want something like a `select` control, but using a data list.  If so:

Here's my **BlazrInputSelectList** control that does that.

```cs
@using System.Linq.Expressions;
@typeparam TValue
@typeparam TListItem

<InputText @attributes=this.AdditionalAttributes
           list="@listId"
           Value=@this.selectedValue
           ValueChanged=OnChange
           ValueExpression="() => this.selectedValue"
           placeholder="@this.PlaceholderText" />

<datalist id="@listId">

    @foreach (var option in this.DisplayOptionsItems)
    {
        <option>@(this.OptionDelegateText(option))</option>
    }

</datalist>

@code {
    [Parameter] public TValue? Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<TValue> ValueChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Expression<Func<TValue>>? ValueExpression { get; set; }

    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public IEnumerable<TListItem> DisplayOptionsItems { get; set; } = default!;
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public Func<TListItem, string> OptionDelegateText { get; set; } = default!;
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public Func<TListItem, string, bool> OptionDelegateFinder { get; set; } = default!;
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public Func<TListItem, TValue> OptionDelegateValue { get; set; } = default!;

    [Parameter] public string PlaceholderText { get; set; } = "Select a Value";
    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)] public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>? AdditionalAttributes { get; set; }

    private string? selectedValue;
    private readonly string listId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        // Check we have all the delegates. If not throw an exception before we try and render a null list
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(this.DisplayOptionsItems);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(this.OptionDelegateText);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(this.OptionDelegateFinder);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(this.OptionDelegateValue);
    }

    private async Task OnChange(string value)
    {
        selectedValue = value;
        var item = this.DisplayOptionsItems.FirstOrDefault(item => this.IsItem(item));
        if (item is not null)
            await this.ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(this.OptionDelegateValue(item));
    }

    private bool IsItem(TListItem item)
    {
        if (selectedValue is not null)
            return this.OptionDelegateFinder.Invoke(item, selectedValue);

        return false;
    }
}
```

You implement it in a form like this.  I've shown cached and uncached delegate versions.  The second cached version is more efficient [the anonymous methods are rebuilt every time the component renders], but has a little more code.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
<pre>Selected Guid : @_selectedUid </pre>
<pre>Selected Guid1 : @_selectedUid1 </pre>
</div>

<BlazrInputSelectList class="form-control mb-3"
                      @bind-Value=_selectedUid
                      DisplayOptionsItems=this._countries
                      OptionDelegateText="(item) => item.Name"
                      OptionDelegateFinder="(item, value) => item.Name.Equals(value, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)"
                      OptionDelegateValue="(item) => item.Uid" />

<BlazrInputSelectList class="form-control mb-3"
                      @bind-Value=_selectedUid1
                      DisplayOptionsItems=this._countries
                      OptionDelegateText=this.GetOptionText
                      OptionDelegateFinder=this.GetOptionFinder
                      OptionDelegateValue=this.GetOptionValue />

@code {
    private List<Country> _countries = new()
        {
            new(Guid.NewGuid(), "Portugal"),
            new(Guid.NewGuid(), "France"),
            new(Guid.NewGuid(), "Spain"),
        };

    private Guid? _selectedUid;
    private Guid? _selectedUid1;

    public record Country(Guid Uid, string Name);

    private string GetOptionText(Country item)
        => item.Name;

    private Guid? GetOptionValue(Country item)
        => item.Uid;

    private bool GetOptionFinder(Country item, string value)
        => item.Name.Equals(value, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```